# Laravel sessions broken after ubuntu update

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, session, csrf, csrf-protection

I've upgraded my ubuntu server to version 18.04.1. After the upgrade my laravel website keeps displaying TokenMismatchException in every single POST page. The only exception to this rule seems to be the login page, which works for some users and not others.

My local virtual machine with version 16.04.4 works normally.

I'm stuck in this all morning, with my website down.

Comment: I'm receiving downvotes, did I forget post some information?

Comment: you need to debug all steps of csrf protection. Insufficient info to figure out

Comment: It seems that the website is failing at creating the session entries on the database. When comparing my local database with the live one, the live one is empty.

Comment: There are no erros being displayed since the session not being created happens when the previous page loads. I've tried creating a session using the session() command and it also does nothing without displaying erros

Comment: is it work if you change driver to file `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),` in config/session.php ?

Comment: I'm using the database driver, that does not seem to be the issue since both machines have the same configuration

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts including an server rollback that did not immediately work, it just randomly started working by showing less and less errors until they were all gone. I'm not exactly sure what was the key to solving it.

My final version included:

- SESSION_DRIVER => 'database'
- SESSION_DOMAIN => null
- Complete server rollback
- Many cache clears
- Erasing all remember_keys
- Erasing all browser data